# T- Sql date time conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

All my columns are `varchar` so I used common expression table to convert `[Column 0]` to `datetime` since `[Column 0]` contains date in this format `2012-02-28 00:00:08.000`

```
WITH pss AS 
(
select CONVERT(datetime, [Column 0]) as t, [Column 1], [Column 2], [Column 3], [Column 4], [Column 5], [Column 6]
from PWS where [Column 0]  like '%2/28%'
)
select *from pss where datepart(HOUR,[t]) >= '11' AND datepart(HOUR,[t]) <= '12'
```

I am getting the following message

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: you can check with the `ISDATE()` function which values do not convert properly.

Comment: yes ISDATE() returns all rows with 1 meaning all are valid datetimes

Comment: @AI25 - Does the ISDATE() also only returns 1 if you remove the where clause?

Comment: @lieven yes all of them return 1

Comment: Can you post a minimum set of data that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to provide the hint with CONVERT as to the structure of the date within a varchar. The ymd sequence will be recognised as 102:

```
convert(datetime, '2012-02-28 00:00:08.000', 102)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for a description of CONVERT and the available datetime styles

Comment: I've done it successfully with 102 (which is in fact just the date part). If you want the full datetime then 121 matches the delimiters you say you're using

Comment: However your SQL is looking for forward slashes which would be 111 for date only. So what format are your dates stored in?

Answer (score 0):

Values for datetime data types earlier than January 01, 1753 are not permitted in SQL Server. SQL Server accepts the dates ranging from year 1753 to year 9999 only. If Column0 in your table contains dates earlier than Jan 01 1753, you might have this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, I would use a cursor* to loop through each row, then, for each row, attempt to CONVERT the value of [Column 0] to a DateTime. Surround the CONVERT attempt with a TRY..CATCH block, then in the CATCH block, output some diagnostics so that you can tell exactly which row caused the error.

NOTE * : yes, cursors are generally to be avoided, but in this diagnostic situation I think it is useful.